# How to recursively add zeroes to a file name

Tags: shell-script, rename

I have a folder with these files:

```
03.jpg
04.jpg
05.jpg
99.jpg
```

I want to rename these files to

```
003.jpg
004.jpg
005.jpg
099.jpg
```

by using a bash script. How can I do this?

Comment: `cd path_to/folder_name ; rename 's/^/0/' ??.jpg`

Comment: `for f in path_to/folder_name/[0-9][0-9].jpg; do mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/0$(basename "$f")"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf("%.03d", $&)/e' *jpg
```

(remove -n switch when your tests are OK)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: The perl rename script is sometimes known as `prename`.  e.g. it is included as `/usr/bin/prename` in Debian's `perl` package.